Consumption based asset pricing - covariance of consumption and returns impact on asset price
I'm reading about consumption based asset pricing model. I don't fully understand a basic equation below.
Let's start with the law:
$$
p_t = E_t\left[\beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)}p_{t+1}\right]
$$
Let $m_{t+1} = \beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)}$ and $R_{t+1} = \frac{p_{t+1}}{p_t}$
Then our equation becomes (I've omitted the $t$ subscripts):
$$
1 = E(m R)
$$
The book says to define $R^f = \frac{1}{E(m)}$ as the risk-free rate. Then we can rewrite the above as:
$$
1 = E(m)E(R) + cov(m,R)
$$
Multiply by $R^f$:
$$
R^f = E(R) + R^f cov(m,R)
$$
Or
$$
E(R) = R^f\left[1 - R^f cov(m,R)\right]
$$
Alternatively written as an excess return:
$$
E(R-R^f) = -R^f cov(m,R)
$$
I don't understand this - doesn't this effectively say that any asset whose returns are correlated positively with consumption will have a negative excess return? That's the majority of stocks, commodities etc. Almost all stock sectors (energy, industrial, consumer discretionary etc.) will have returns positively correlated with consumption.

If consumption $c_{t+1}$ goes up, then $u'(c_{t+1})$ decreases so $m_{t+1}$ also decreases. So positive correlation between consumption and returns corresponds to a negative value of $cov(m, R)$ (I think).
